# How to run javascript function from MVC View?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried everything what I have found on the Internet, but nothing worked. I have an external javascript file called calendarCZ.js, the relative path is: ~/Scripts/calendarCZ.js.

I want this js file to include to my View called getSideBar.cshtml.

I have written this in Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/calendarCZ.js")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

I have written this in getSideBar.cshtml:

```
Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/calendarCZ.js")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
@section Scripts{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/calendarCZ.js")">
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/calendarCZ.js")
        @if (ViewBag.JS == true)
        {
            printCalendarCZ(@Model.events);
        }
    </script>

}
```

And he is still ignoring my script with printCalendarCZ(events) function.
**Error: Identifier printCalendarCZ does not exist in the current context.**

Does anyone really know how to include the javascript in MVC 5?

Thanks for replies.

Petr

Comment: Having a `script` tag with content isn't valid html. You should have 2 script tags and put your src in one and content in the other

Comment: No, the tags should be siblings. Put your function call after you load your library so that the function is defined when it gets called.

Comment: There is a different error: C# Tag @if and his body is recognized as a C# code and I want to call javascript function. I can not imagine, that somebody can write this as a solution, how to call javascript function from view. I want to call the function without user interactivity, I want to call it after a page load.

Comment: you are calling the same script file 3 times? why?

Comment: Because I thought that it ignores all the calls. I think the error is in the call of the javascript function inside `@if { //call }` But somebody uploaded this as a solution to a similar question. I think I have to use `window.onload()`, but it ignores too.

Comment: ... no errors now, but no Calendar is rendered too.

Answer (score 0):

try directly using script tag

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/calendarCZ.js")"></script>
```

or

```
//take the relative path
<script src="../Scripts/calendarCZ.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to do this.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/calendarCZ.js")
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        @if (ViewBag.JS == true)
        {
            @:printCalendarCZ(@Model.events);
        }

    });
</script>
```

or

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/calendarCZ.js")
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var jsValue = @ViewBag.JS;
        if (jsValue == true) {
            printCalendarCZ(@Model.events);
        }

    });
</script>
```

and don't forget to include jquery.